# php switch am I doing it wrong?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm trying to make multiple pages in 1 file and i have this

```
<?

switch($action){
    case "add":
       add();
       break;
    default:
       hello();
       break;
}

function add() {

    echo "hello";
}

function hello() {

    echo "hello1";
}
?>
```

but when I got to `****.php?action=add` I still get "hello1"

what am I doing wrong with this to where I get hello

Comment: Quick and dirty: you have to test for `switch($_REQUEST['action']) {`

Comment: and use <?php since <? can be evaluated as xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch on `$_GET['action']` instead.

Comment: You might consider using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`, in case the request ever comes from a POST.

Comment: you are the man thanks! I will mark the answer when the 10 minutes are up!

Comment: I don't think using `$_REQUEST` is a good idea - it's best to strictly switch only on the querystring parameter, not a form field. What if you have two with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php


       $action=  $_GET['action']
       //$_REQUEST, by default, contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. 
       // $action=  $_REQUEST['action']; 
        switch($action){
            case "add":
               add();
               break;
            default:
               hello();
               break;
        }

        function add() {

            echo "hello";
        }

        function hello() {

            echo "hello1";
        }
        ?>
```